# Simulia Abaqus installation error under Linux (Mint 17.2)

Tags: linux, installation, java

When executing the setup script from a **Simulia Abaqus 6.14** installation directory under **Linux (Mint 17.2)**, I receive an error upon launching the installer. The Abaqus installer appears to run in Java, hence I installed the required **JRE (v6)** first. However, the installer still reports a `LaunchAnywhere` application error related to some character encoding:

```
Launching installer...

An internal LaunchAnywhere application error has occurred and this application cannot proceed. (LAX)

Stack Trace:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed \uxxxx encoding.
    at java.util.Properties.loadConvert(Unknown Source) 
    at java.util.Properties.load0(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Properties.load(Unknown Source)
    at com.zerog.common.java.util.PropertiesUtil.loadProperties(DashoA10*..)
    at com.zerog.lax.LAX.<init>(DashA10*..)
    at com.zerog.lax.LAX.main(DashA10*..)
```

Any idea what may cause this error and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered the answer (through) Google while writing the question:

Apparently, this is a known issue with `InstallAnywhere` installers. There is an easy workaround, in your terminal you simply have to call:

`unset PS1`

or

`export PS1=">"`

The former worked for me and the restarting the `setup` script in the same terminal after unsetting `PS1` allowed the installation to proceeded without issues.